# warning C4715: 'operator==' : not all control paths return a value

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error and I do not understand why. The compiler told me that it was in this section.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
bool operator==(const Bitmap& b1, const Bitmap& b2){
    // TODO: complete the == operator
    if ((b1.height == b2.height) && (b1.width == b2.width))
    {

        for (int r = 0; r < b1.height; r++)
        {

            for (int c = 0; c < b1.width; c++)
            {
                if (b1.get(r, c) == b2.get(r, c))
                {

                }
                else
                    return false;
            }

        }

    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Imagine if b1.height, b2.height, b1.width, and b2.width were all zero.  In that case you'd enter the first code block, but never enter into either of the two for-loops.... and you wouldn't hit the "return false" at the end either since that is only for the "else" case.  Instead you'd just drop off the bottom of the function and the value returned by the function would be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The diagnostic from the compiler is exactly what it says.

Note that if the for loop runs through to the end, without taking the if condition that returns `false`, if `r` reaches the `b1.height` value, the execution path will reach the end of this function without an explicit `return`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear.

```
bool operator==(const Bitmap& b1, const Bitmap& b2){

    if ((b1.height == b2.height) && (b1.width == b2.width))
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < b1.height; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < b1.width; c++)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
        return ???;   // What should be returned here?
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells what is wrong.

```
bool operator==(const Bitmap& b1, const Bitmap& b2){
    // TODO: complete the == operator
    if ((b1.height == b2.height) && (b1.width == b2.width))
    {

        for (int r = 0; r < b1.height; r++)
        {

            for (int c = 0; c < b1.width; c++)
            {
                if (b1.get(r, c) == b2.get(r, c))
                {

                }
                else
                    return false;
            }

        }
        return true; // I guess you forgot this line

    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is precisely what the error says. The compiler doesn't know if there is a possibility that the code in the nested for loop can ever be triggered. Assuming the first condition is true, there is a chance that the code never gets to the return statement. Therefore the compiler will make sure that something always is returned, regardless of whatever condition you give it.

```
bool operator==(const Bitmap& b1, const Bitmap& b2){
if ((b1.height == b2.height) && (b1.width == b2.width))
{
    // The compiler expects a return statement that is always reachable inside this if.

    for (int r = 0; r < b1.height; r++)
    {

        for (int c = 0; c < b1.width; c++)
        {
            if (b1.get(r, c) == b2.get(r, c))
            {

            }
            else
                return false; //This isn't always reachable.
        }

    }
}
else
    return false; // This case is covered, so nothing wrong here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

```
bool operator==(const Bitmap& b1, const Bitmap& b2){
// TODO: complete the == operator
if ((b1.height == b2.height) && (b1.width == b2.width))
{

for (int r = 0; r < b1.height; r++)
{

    for (int c = 0; c < b1.width; c++)
    {
        if (b1.get(r, c) == b2.get(r, c))
        {

        }
        else
            return false;
    }

}
// if your function runs to end of for loop, you get to here
}
else
    return false;
//then here
return false;   //<-- add this
}
```